# Need help filling in blanks on a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that contains Names and associated numbers. The issue is that the values don't associate with the Names. Here is an example below:

[image]

All the values should be associated with the name that starts before the values start appearing. The result should look something like this:

[image]

I am struggling to come up with the logic that would get this done and any help would be appreciated. I can figure out how to remove the blank values on my own shown in the second example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

If your **'Name'** column don't contains NaN's(it contains `''` or `' '`) then make use of [`replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) method(If it contains `NaN's` then Ignore this step):

```
df['Name']=df['Name'].replace('',np.nan,regex=True)
df['Name']=df['Name'].replace(' ',np.nan,regex=True)
```

Just use [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) method:

```
df['Name']=df['Name'].ffill()
```

**OR**

you can also do this by [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) method:

```
df['Name']=df['Name'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output